# SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: table: SELECT "items".* FROM "items" WHERE (table) ORDER BY created_at DESC

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm getting the following error:

```
SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: table: SELECT "items".* FROM "items" WHERE (table) ORDER BY created_at DESC
```

I'm trying to implement a basic search.

Comment: Could you please show the code, which you call before getting the error? I guess, it's your search method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you call `where` method with an invalid argument, something that evaluates to `"table"`. Something like:

```
Item.where("table")
```

`where` should take a hash:

```
Item.where(column: "value")
```

or a string with an SQL condition:

`Item.where("items.column = 'value'")`

Both evaluate to the following SQL query:

```
SELECT  `items`.* FROM `items` WHERE `items`.`column` = 'value'
```